# Whose PATH value is the default PATH value in a crontab file?

Tags: cron, path

root's default PATH is

```
$ sudo su
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

After creating /etc/cron.d/myjob

```
35 * * * * tim ( date && echo $PATH && date ) > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

`/tmp/cron.log` shows the default value of PATH is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin
```

Is the default PATH value in a crontab file not the one for the root? Why?

Whose PATH value is it?

WIll the default PATH value be different if I add the job in `/etc/crontab` or a file under `/etc/cronb.d/`?

Does it matter which user is specified in the cron job? (such as `tim` in the above example)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the version of `cron` you’re using. I seem to remember you use Debian; `cron` there sets a number of variables up as follows:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the [`cron(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/cron.8) daemon. `SHELL` is set to `/bin/sh`, and `LOGNAME` and `HOME` are set from the `/etc/passwd` line of the `crontab`’s owner. `PATH` is set to `"/usr/bin:/bin"`. `HOME`, `SHELL`, and `PATH` may be overridden by settings in the `crontab`; `LOGNAME` is the user that the job is running from, and may not be changed.

(See [the `crontab`](https://manpages.debian.org/crontab.5) manpage for details.)

Comment: in Ubuntu 18.04 the default PATH is `/usr/bin:/bin` , and in Ubuntu 22.04 the default PATH is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` , quite the mouthful! (even for users other than root. that was unexpected! it's a sudo group member though..)

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't mention a specific `cron` implementation, let me assume that you are talking about the original UNIX cron implementation.

There is a default `PATH` for `root` (which is `/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`) and another for non-root users (which is `/usr/bin:`).

The related values may be overwritten by entries like:

```
PATH=
SUPATH=
```

in the file `/etc/default/cron`.

See: https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/cmd/cron/

See also: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1m/cron.1m.html and http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/crontab.1.html

If you refer to a clone implementation, you should mention which implementation you have in mind...