# Does cron modify execution environment and make tor servce not change exit node?

Tags: cron, tor

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478636/674, cron modifies the execution environment to execute a job.

1. When I run `sudo service tor reload` twice directly in bash, it
   always shows two different IP addresses

   ```
   $ sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip; sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip
   12.345.678.901
   987.654.321.00
   ```

   Is it correct that `sudo service tor reload` will most likely change
   tor exit node, and thus change the public IP address?
2. But when I create a cron job in `/etc/cron.d/myjob`,

   ```
   * * * * * tim (sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip; sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip) > /tmp/cron.log
   ```

   every time I check `/tmp/cron.log`, it always shows two identical IP
   addresses, although the IP address changes from job  to
   job (when the next scheduled job overwrites the log, it will show two identical IP addresses not identical to the two before overwriting). Same when I insert `sleep 20` between the two reload:

   ```
   * * * * * tim (sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip; sleep 20; sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip) > /tmp/cron.log
   ```

   As a cron job, why does `sudo service tor reload` fail to  change
   the IP address? How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be a coincidence? Could it be one reload has not finished? Could it be that both reloads are not being done? Am I making any sense?

Comment: It happens consistently. Try it yourself, and you will see.

Comment: If the IP addresses change every time you run the cron job, isn’t it doing its job (from your perspective), even though the two runs inside a cron job don’t?

Comment: @StephenKitt You are correct. That should do my job. I repeat it twice in one cron job, just to let me check the overwritten log to make sure the IP changes. But it doesn't change within one job, and surprises me.

Comment: @StephenKitt Can it be because in the crontab file, I specify a non-root user `tim` to run the cron job, while the cron job contains sudo?  Will the sudo command fail because there is no way to provide the root password?

Comment: If `sudo` fails, then the service won’t restart at all. You could try running the job as root without `sudo`, I’m not sure what the benefit is of running as `tim` and then using `sudo` to run `service tor reload` as root anyway.

Comment: @StephenKitt  Thanks. Would running the job as root with sudo be okay too, although sudo isn't necessary? Suppose the command of the job is a shell script containing sudo.

Comment: @StephenKitt  For example, if I may ask?

Comment: Actually no, `sudo` never asks for a password when run as root — I thought this was configurable, but it doesn’t seem to be.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Thanks. if you were me, into which crontab file would you place a script containing `sudo service tor reload; torsocks  curl ipinfo.io/ip`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is: in the job line, the command  uses `sudo`, while the user field is a nonroot user `tim`. I don't provide `tim`'s password asked for by `sudo`.

I am still trying to understand what the best practice of writing the user and command fields of a cron job. [Are cron tasks in `/etc/cron.d/` files supposed to not contain `sudo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478779/are-cron-tasks-in-etc-cron-d-files-supposed-to-not-contain-sudo)