# How does cron set the environment variables in /etc/cron.d/* and /etc/cron.d/?

Tags: cron

In Debian's manpage  of cron,

> The files in /etc/cron.d/ are independent of /etc/crontab: they do not, for example, **inherit** environment variable settings from **it**.

and from the LinuxQuestions.org Forum: [/etc/crontab vs /etc/cron.d vs /var/spool/cron/crontabs/](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/etc-crontab-vs-etc-cron-d-vs-var-spool-cron-crontabs-853881/),

> **scripts that are in /etc/cron.d/ don't load environment variables.**
>
> I'm assuming you added your command as root **in the /etc/crontab file**. If that's the fact then **executing the crontab line will load the user's environment variables** which **don't get loaded when you put the script in /etc/cron.d.**

I was wondering what the sentences highlighted by me mean? What is the "inherit"ance from?

1. For `/etc/cron.d/*`, [cron reset the environment variables, so don't
   load environment variables of the given users in the job definition
   lines.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478634/whose-path-value-is-the-default-path-value-in-a-crontab-file/478636#478636)

   After creating `/etc/cron.d/myjob`

   ```
   35 * * * * t   echo $PATH  > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
   ```

   `/tmp/cron.log` shows the default value of PATH is:

   ```
   /usr/bin:/bin
   ```

   which isn't the root's PATH:

   ```
   $ sudo su
   # echo $PATH
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
   ```
2. In `/etc/crontab`, I added

   ```
   * * * * * root   echo $PATH    > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
   * * * * * t    echo $PATH  > /tmp/cron.log.1 2>&1
   ```

   Then The PATH value for a root's cron job isn't the root's

   ```
   $ cat /tmp/cron.log
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   ```

   The PATH value of my cron job isn't mine (modified in`~/.profile`)
   either

   ```
   $ cat /tmp/cron.log.1
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

   $ echo $PATH
   /home/t/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/mssql-tools/bin

   $ less ~/.profile | grep PATH
   PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: You can find out easily enough. Create a job that does `env >/tmp/env` and compare the various results from starting it in different cron files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please see my update.

Answer (score 4):

From `man 5 crontab`:

> An  active line in a crontab will be either an **environment** setting or a cron command.

That is: a not commented line (`#`) could be:

```
PATH = /bin:/sbin
```

Which will set the value of `PATH` for the whole `crontab` file.

If that value is not set, the built-in value (in-code) [as shown on this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401622/265604) is used.

Example of a crontab file setting the PATH:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash 
MAILTO=root
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin

# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#.---------------- minute (m) (0 - 59)
#|      .------------- hour (h) (0 - 23)
#|      |       .---------- day of month (dom) (1 - 31)
#|      |       |       .------- month (mon) (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
#|      |       |       |       .---- day of week (dow) (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
#                                       .---- user
#|      |       |       |       |       |
#*      *       *       *       *       root   echo "the command to be executed"
#
#m      h       dom     mon     dow     user   command
*       *       *       *       *       root   echo "A crontab file test"
```