# Debian 10: root crontab is running as user

Tags: cron

I've added a job to `root`'s crontab

```
# crontab -l | tail -n 1
*/3,13,29,43 * * * * /root/bin/check_network.sh
#
```

However, it appears to be running as my normal user, `rwb`.

The `rwb` account (not the `root` account) is getting mail about the job failing, and it's failing because

> `/root/bin/check_network.sh: line 26: iw: command not found`

But of course `iw` is at `/use/sbin/iw` wchich is on `root`'s `$PATH` but not `rwb`'s.

What's going on?!
How can I run my root cron job?

**Update**

Changingthe command from `iw` to `/usr/sbin/iw` seems to have got it working, so there must be some difference in the `$PATH` when cron is running compared to a normal bash window.

Comment: First thing I can think of is that your script is dropping privileges, you probably want to paste it. The fact that it knows about `iw` in the error means that the script has been started, and because it's in `/root` it certainly started with root privileges.

Comment: is root aliased to rwb in /etc/aliases? it's a pretty common practice for root's mail to be set to their fist non-system user.   check with `grep root /etc/aliases`.  Also, check the headers of the mail, particularly headers like `To:` and `Delivered-To:`.

Comment: Yes I have `root:rwb` in `/etc/aliases` which explains why `root`'s mail is going to `rwb`. Ta :)

Comment: OK, that means the cron job is running as root, which also means that the problem is a PATH issue.  Remember that the PATH in cron is not necessarily the same as PATH in a login shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does cron set the environment variables in /etc/cron.d/\* and /etc/cron.d/?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479522/how-does-cron-set-the-environment-variables-in-etc-cron-d-and-etc-cron-d)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `su` to become root when setting up that crontab?

On Debian 10, `man crontab` says:

> Note that su(8) can confuse crontab and that if you are running inside of su(8) you should always use the -u option for safety's sake.

In Debian 10 release, Debian abandoned the old `su` command from the `shadow-utils` codebase, and moved into `su` from the `util-linux` codebase. This caused a number of subtle changes.

The default set-up of Debian 10 allows multiple people to have root access and still have their own personal preferences take effect while using root privileges if they wish. But as a consequence, using just `su` or `sudo -s` will result in an incomplete change of environment variables: for example, after transitioning from `rwb` to `root` with a plain `su`, the `USER` environment variable will still have a value of `rwb`. *This variable is what some programs and scripts use to identify the user.*

So if you go to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` and look at the files in there, I bet you'll find your cron job definition is actually in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/rwb`, not in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. Effectively, you still edited your own personal crontab file, not root's.

If you want to "fully become root", with a complete re-initialization of environment variables, you'll need to use `su -` or `sudo -i`.

Comment: In `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` there are two files: `root` and `rwb` and each of these is identical to the output of `crontab -l` when run as the respective users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an issue with the **environment**; specifically the $PATH environment variable in `cron`. I mess about with 2-3 different distros (mostly Debian), and the **environment** is not always the same. I use a little trick to get `cron` to tell me what it's environment is:

###### Add the following line (or similar) to your `crontab`:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/printenv > /home/my/cronenv.txt 2>&1
```

###### Compare that against the environment reported from your interactive shell (`bash` in this case):

```
pi@4b:~ $ printenv
```

As you'll likely see, there are substantial diffs between the two environments. There are [various solutions for modifying the environment for `cron`](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cron-environment-and-cron-job-failures), but for my purposes I find that simply making a habit of calling out the full path to an executable/command eliminates the need for most changes to the `cron` environment.

###### WRT `root's crontab`, it is not the same as your user's `crontab`:

```
pi@4b:~ $ sudo crontab -e
```

This gets you the `root crontab` that is substantially different from your `user crontab`. As before, you can run the `printenv` in the `root crontab` to examine the diffs in environments. When you need *elevated privileges* in a `cron` job, this is *the way to go*.

Know that this may be handled differently on some systems, but on my Debian-based systems it works well AFAIC. You need not enter `sudo` for privilege elevation in the `root crontab` since you are running the `cron` job/script as `root`.